# Register a new user to Strapi

Tags: postman, registration, strapi

I am very new to strapi and trying to add a new user from postman but I'm unable to do that. It shows `statusCode 403` . I understand that I have to give a permission to the specific role first but there is no permission shown for `Users` collection, which is the default collection when strapi get installed.

I'm doing some registration from my frontend but haven't started with the `post` yet as I want to see first if the submission is working from postman. Unfortunately it gets denied as it's showing forbidden message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be permissions for Users. It's the last item under Settings-Roles-Permissions-User-Permissions.

> USERS-PERMISSIONS
>
> Define all allowed actions for the users-permissions plugin.